# 404 on @RepositoryRestResource's url in JUnits

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, junit4

Something is missing or misconfigured for JUnits - I can't find. 
Getting a `404` instead of `200` in Junits. The application at  `http://localhost:8080/app` shows the *expected response*.

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.github.anandchakru</groupId>
    <artifactId>jtest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- DB -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.13</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.11</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**application.yml** [both main & test are identical]

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework: INFO
    org.hibernate: ERROR
    jtest: DEBUG
  file: jtest.log
spring: 
  datasource: 
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cifi3?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
    username: tester
    password: tester
  jpa: 
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
```

**JTestInit.java**

```
@Configuration
@EntityScan({ "jtest" })
@ComponentScan({ "jtest" })
@SpringBootApplication
public class JTestInit {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("jtest");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(JTestInit.class, args);
        logger.debug("Initialized CifiCore.");
    }
}
```

**AppRepo.java**

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "app")
public interface AppRepo extends PagingAndSortingRepository<App, Long> {}
```

**App.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "app")
public class App {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long appId;
    private String appName;
    //getters,setters
}
```

**AppRepoTest.java**

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

@WebMvcTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Import({ JTestInit.class })
public class AppRepoTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    ObjectMapper json = new ObjectMapper();

    @Test
    public void testFindAll() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/app/")).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

**Browser Response:**

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "apps" : [ ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/app{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/profile/app"
    },
    "search" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/app/search"
    }
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 0,
    "totalPages" : 0,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

## **AppRepoTest - Why??????**

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<404>
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:55)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers.lambda$matcher$9(StatusResultMatchers.java:619)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:195)
    at jtest.AppRepoTest.testFindAll(AppRepoTest.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

Comment: Try annotating the test class with `@AutoConfigureMockMvc`?

Comment: `@WebMvcTest includes` includes `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` & `@AutoConfigureMvc` - as expected didn't help.

Comment: in testFindAll() try running the test with /app (remove the ending / ) instead of /app/

Comment: Changing to /app didn't help

Comment: @AnandRockzz: Just going from your answer below, I assume this _did_ help in the end...

Answer (score 0):

`@WebMvcTest` should be used only for the `Controllers`. Hence, `@RepositoryRestResource` class was **not** initialized.

Replacing it with `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` and `@SpringBootTest` did the trick.

**Other similar Test utility annotations:**

`@WebMvcTest` - for controllers

`@JsonTest` - for JSON marshaling and unmarshalling

`@DataJpaTest` - for repositories

`@RestClientTests` - for REST clients

`@SpringBootTest` - for everything else